# How to redirect to success after POST method in Django 2

Tags: django, url, view, message

I would like to know how a `GET` OR `POST` requests can be handled from a FormView class to render a unbound form for `GET` and POST the form to database for `POST`  and subsequently redirect to success page (info message).

What template to use for `GET` and `POST` methods and how to include message after redirect to success URL?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.views import View

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import MyPlaceForm
from .models import Place
from django.urls.base import reverse_lazy


from django.contrib import messages


#Ceate your class-based views here.
class MapView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        'Display map'
        return render(request,template_name='index.html')

# Handling forms with class-based view
class PlaceFormView(View):
    form_class = MyPlaceForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'name.html'

    # Provide Blank Form if GET request
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

# Provide a message if POST request
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        success_url=reverse_lazy('success')
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>

            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
            return reverse_lazy(success_url)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path
from addismap.views import MapView,PlaceFormView


urlpatterns=[
    path('map/',MapView.as_view()),
    path('place/', PlaceFormView.as_view(), name='post-place'),
    path('place/success/',PlaceFormView.as_view(), name='success')

    ]
```

Comment: You're not using a FormView. If you were, all of that code would be done for you.

Comment: Daniel Roseman Can you suggest an edit?

Comment: Inherit from FormView, delete your get and post methods.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/), you can do something like this:

```
# views.py    
if request.method == "POST":

    if form.is_valid():

        # <process form cleaned data>
        messages.success(request, 'Form updated with success.')
        return redirect('/success-page')

    else:       
        messages.error(request, 'Ops! Something went wrong')
        return redirect('/error-page')
```

In your template page you can get the message using a for loop code:

```
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div {% if message.tags %} class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" {% endif %}>
    <span>{{ message }}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**Edit1**: Make sure you've imported the message tag and redirect in your views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get No success_url to redirect to error, although i put 'registration' as success_url.

Comment: You do not need a "success-page" specifically, you can redirect back to the same page of your form passing the success message